# c++11 reverse iterator and lower_bound

Tags: c++, c++11, reverse-iterator

I have the following example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, int> a;
  a[8] = 1;
  a[5] = 1;
  a[1] = 1;
  a[2] = 1;

  std::cout << a.begin()->first << std::endl;

  std::cout << a.rbegin()->first << std::endl;
  std::cout << (++a.rbegin())->first << std::endl;
  std::cout << (--a.rbegin())->first << std::endl;

  std::cout << (a.lower_bound(6))->first << std::endl;
}
```

When I execute it I get this output:

```
1
8
5
5
8
```

I have two questions. The first is why `++a.rbegin()` and `--a.rbegin()` iterate in the same direction? Is the iterator returned from `a.rbegin()` not a bidirectional iterator?

The second question is why does `a.lower_bound(6)->first` return 8 instead of 5? Based on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound, it should return an iterator to the first element "not less than key". So I would have thought 5 would be returned since 8 > 6.

Comment: `--a.rbegin()` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: `--a.rbegin()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: “Not less than key” means “equal or greater”, so 8 is the first that fits. 5 is less than. And as far as I know decrementing an iterative that’s at the beginning is undefined behavior.

Comment: `lower_bound` returns the first element that is >= the one you are searching for.

Comment: For your second question, it returns "not less than key".  Is 5 not less than 6?

Comment: What do you expect to find before the very first element???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--a.rbegin() is a UB.

`lower_bound(val)` returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range which does not compare less than `val`. `5` is not "not less than `6`" so you get the iterator to `8` correctly